# Excel IF Function to Validate existence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is totally me and the lack of coffee. But I am trying to write a formula to look for whats in Cells D3&E3 in another sheet, if it finds it in that combo bring back VALID, if not bring back !!INVALID!!.

I seem to be flubbing somewhere in my concoction because if it doesn't match the combo in the list it brings back #N/A instead of !!INVALID!!.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D4,E4),'PCdb 2-27-2017'!E:E,1,FALSE)=(D4&E4),"VALID","!!INVALID!!")
```

[Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qipfc.png)

[Search for it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owc8P.png)

Comment: Use `iferror()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little off.

The IF statement works like this - if the first statement is true, return the second statement, else return the third.  The problem with this is that the first statement has to return TRUE, FALSE or an equivalent for it to work.

In the case where the concatenated string isn't found, the return value from the first statement is #N/A, which the IF statement cannot evaluate, so instead the #N/A is passed through to whole function and returned.  To fix this, you need to check if the VLOOKUP statement is returning #N/A, and use that return value for the first statement.

This correction should work fine:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D4&E4,'PCdb 2-27-2017'!E:E,1,FALSE)),"!!INVALID!!","VALID")
```

Let me know if this fix works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an easy solution.

=IF(VLOOKUP(D4&E4,'PCdb 2-27-2017'!E:E,1,FALSE)=1,"VALID","!!INVALID!!")

resp=1 or whatever the value that the VLOOKUP reads out of column 1 acoordingly